# How to validate thousands of image URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, product, validation

I have multi-vendors and each one has thousands of products and each product has at-least one image URL. we've imported their CSV file to our Magento 1.9 and looks like there are bunch of broken links. would anybody can help me what is the best way to validate those URL links.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a *best* way but I use this vba code in an excel file to download them. It will tell you which are not downloaded and therefore which are not valid URLs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383614/get-pictures-from-a-url-and-then-rename-the-picture